# Why might my ceiling fan have been disconnected?

Tags: electrical

[image]

[image]

Hi. We have been in our house for a couple of years and the ceiling fan in our conservatory has never woked. All the plugs worked fine.

Today, I took the fan down and found there was no power getting to the fan. I then check the spur coming off the house plug sockets and could see one set of connections that were fine but another which had seemly been cut at at the entry point. Lookin at the photo, it isnt a clean cut so i wonder if it had snapped.

Can anyone think why this might have disconnected? My underatanding is that these fans aren’t too electric hungry.

If not, does anyone have any tips how to reconnect with the wire being so close to the wall?

Thanks
Ian

Comment: Cables don't "snap". That was cut, but who knows why. You'll have to find some slack in the cable to reconnect, or add a junction box upstream and run a new cable.

Comment: it could be annoying (squeaky, rattles), it might disrupt the air too much for some people (severe allergies), or it might be dirty and hot or old and unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

> Lookin at the photo, it isnt a clean cut so i wonder if it had snapped.

Not a chance. Cables don't snap easily. And they don't cut easily either, which is why the cut isn't clean.

> Can anyone think why this might have disconnected?

My best guess (and it's only a guess) is that the fan was installed by a DIYer, without getting Part P sign-off by an electrician, and in advance of selling the house the DIYer/vendor disconnected it (with extreme prejudice) as they didn't want any liability for it.

*(The buyers of my last house may have come across a few similar things...)*

> If not, does anyone have any tips how to reconnect with the wire being so close to the wall?

It may be possible to connect to the existing short wires with crimping. Might be worth talking to your local electrician for this.

Or you may be able to use this short wire to draw-through a new longer cable (although I'd guess the friction would probably be too high, and you'd risk stripping the new cable on corners.... On second thoughts: please don't try this idea).

Or you may have to bash a hole in the wall further back along the cable, in order to joint the cable somewhere where there's enough slack in the cable.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this was a permanent way to get others in the house to not turn the fan on.